# Passing along ellipsis arguments to two different functions?

Tags: r

How do I write a main function flexible enough to pass extra arguments along to multiple functions?  Simple attempts have failed:

```
> mainF <- function(f1,f2,...) {
+     f2( X=f1(...), ... )
+ }
> mainF(function(x) x, function(X, y) X*y, x=5, y=3)
Error in f2(X = f1(...), ...) : unused argument (x = 5)
```

I can see how this might be possible by examining formals and matching call arguments in the ellipsis to the formals of each function.  Is there a better way, though?

Comment: you can pass a list to one of the subfunctions, ie ` mainF <- function(f1,f2,..., args.f2 = list())`.

Comment: Other than the idiom @baptiste mentions (which is often used in the R sources), you are into argument processing territory. You can grab `...`, get the argument names of `f1` and `f2` via `formals()`, then process the grabbed `...` list to extract arguments for each function. What happens however when `f1` and `f2` have the same named arguments? This is why baptiste's idea is nice a simple; you just need `do.call(f2, args.f2)` to call `f2` with the correct set of arguments as specified by the user.

Comment: That's a great idiom.  I've probably seen it a million times in base R but it didn't occur to me to do it that way for some reason.  @baptiste post as an answer?

Comment: You might also wanna check [this question by me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4124900/289572)

Comment: @Henrik That's great.  Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a list to one of the subfunctions, ie

```
mainF <- function(f1, f2, ..., args.f2 = list()) {
     do.call(f2, c(X=f1(...), args.f2))
}

mainF(function(x) x, function(X, y) X*y, x=5, args.f2 = list(y=3))
```

(untested, but you got the gist)