# Passing `...` to functions taking different arguments (including `...`)

Tags: r, function

I understand how to use ellipses when I only want one function to receive those arguments:

```
ok <- function(x, ...){
    sum(x, ...)
}
x.in <- c(1:9, NA)
ok(x.in, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I start getting confused when some functions need only certain parts of `...`. I was thinking of using something like `names(formals(cor))` to test for which arguments in `...` to send where, but I don't see how to do this for `sum` or `plot`. In general, I want to write functions similar to the following:

```
yikes <- function(x, ...){
    plot(x, ...)
    sum(x, ...) + cor(x, ...)
}
x.in <- c(1:9, NA)
x.in.jitter <- jitter(x.in)
yikes(x.in, y=x.in.jitter, na.rm=TRUE, use="na.or.complete", type="o")
```

Ideally, `yikes()` would do the following:

```
plot(x=x.in, y=x.in.jitter, type="o")
sum(x.in, na.rm=TRUE) + cor(x=x.in, y=x.in.jitter, use="na.or.complete")
```

I suspect part of the solution may use `match.call`. How would I get a function like `yikes()` to work? Is this simply a bad idea?

*Edit:* The second link in the first comment goes a long way to answering this question given the situation where you know/ are willing to explicitly describe what parameters get passed to what functions. Using the arguments of functions called directly (e.g., `cor`, `plot`, `sum` in `yikes`), or indirectly (`par` via `plot`) to indicate what arguments supplied via `...` should be used for a particular function is what I am searching for. I understand the case for `cor`, e.g.; but how would one do this for `plot`, without explicitly mentioning `par` or the arguments it takes?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774946/passing-along-ellipsis-arguments-to-two-different-functions) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r) might help.

Comment: @plafort thanks for those links, but does that suggest I need to know what function the `...` goes to (`plot` goes to `par`, e.g.)? Also, does that handle the issue with `sum()` getting the `type="o"` argument? Based on the answers in those questions, I have a feeling that there is not a simple and elegant answer for these cases.

Comment: The second answer addresses the problem you will have if you pass `...` to `cor` and the dots have an `na.rm` argument in them. You need to study that answer more carefully.

Comment: After studying some more, it still seems like something along the lines of `c(names(formals(plot.default)), names(par()))` is required (for plot, e.g.). I'm thinking that in my example, dealing with `sum` is impossible, because anything could go there (nothing to match to). But say you couldn't know that `plot` was sending the `...` to `par`, what then? Is there a way to drill down further with `formals`, applying recursively to any function `plot` (e.g.) sends its `...` to? I get `cor`, that's easy b/c `formals(cor)` shows all (as I mention in my Q)

Comment: No, it's not a bad idea. However, the ellipse lacks clarity in that case. Instead, you can work with separate arguments, e.g., `plot.args`, `sum.args` etc., each of which may be a list containing the additional arguments. Inside the function, you can call the other functions using `do.call` while referring to the function-specific list of additional arguments.