# Dispatch ellipsis (...) to more than one function

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

`...` is fine to dispatch additional arguments to functions within a function. I use it, among others, to maintain parsimonious function declarations with not a ton of arguments. But sometimes, I would need that more than a single function could make use of additional arguments passed to the function.

Maybe an example would make this clear:

```
heart <- structure(c(200, 162, 116, 99, 118, 164, 202, 242, 288, 305, 
                     284, 238, 37, 76, 108, 154, 200, 211, 175, 211, 197, 151, 105, 
                     73), .Dim = c(12L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y")))

# both functions in this function would benefit using `...`
plot_this <- function(xy, ...){
  plot(xy, ...)
  polygon(xy, ...)
}
```

Then, calling this function with arguments that only "concern" one function (ie `asp` for `plot` and `density` for `polygon`) will (most of the time) work but with `warnings`.

```
plot_this(heart, asp=1, density=30)

Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "density" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "density" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "density" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "density" is not a graphical parameter
5: In box(...) : "density" is not a graphical parameter
6: In title(...) : "density" is not a graphical parameter
```

I understand that these warnings are perfectly legitimate and useful.

Is there a mechanism to deal with dispatching ellipsis to the 'right' functions when more use `...` within a function?".

I'm looking for something:

- more elegant than using this pattern `..._polygon` or `args.polygon`
- possibly simpler than around `formals` as answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128401/6101188)
- less rough than `suppressWarnings()`

Comment: See a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774946/passing-along-ellipsis-arguments-to-two-different-functions) and its linked posts

Comment: Thnaks! Precisely I would like to avoid `args.polygon` here, possibly know if there is a simpler way than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128401/6101188).

Comment: edited my post thanks to your comment.

Comment: What's wrong with using `formals`? I'm tempted to close this as unclear as you haven't provided any reasoning for not using the builtin functionality in order to achieve what you need. It mainly sounds to me like "*but I don't wanna!*"

Comment: I thought there could be a simpler way that I'm not aware of but I can manage with formals if there is not.

Comment: `base` plotting functions contain many examples -that I guess could be considered simple/elegant (?)- of either (1) `..., polygon.args = list(arg1 = , ..), plot.args = list(arg1 = ), ...`followed by a `do.call` or `..., arg1.polygon = , arg1.plot = , ...` passed directly to each sub-funtion. See, e.g., `boxplot.default`, `barplot.default`, `legend` etc