# Reading R's documentation, how do I unambiguously match arguments with functions?

Tags: r

In R, entering `?qqplot` leads to a help file on three different functions: `qqplot`, `qqnorm`, and `qqline`. There is only one list of arguments. How do I find out which arguments go with which function?

Here's a facsimile of the qqnorm [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/qqnorm.html).

Comment: The Usage section lists each function along with their respective arguments.

Comment: Sometimes it also lists "...". Does this signify additional arguments?

Comment: The ellipsis argument is a special argument, there are many discussions of it here and in the docs, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5890576/324364) is a good place to start.

Comment: ...or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17688999/324364) discussion, among many others.