# Auto-Update Data for R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, auto-update, shinyapps

so I thought I had figured this out thanks to previous help ([Updating R shiny data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72566334/updating-r-shiny-data)), but I have come across more issues. I didn't notice these issues since I got busy doing other things in my job. But turns out it is not auto-updating the app on shinyapps.io. I'll post the test code I have made in the server section:

```
dftest<-reactiveFileReader(1000,session,"Crop Registration 2022.xlsx",readFunc = read_excel,sheet = "CSV")
  output$table2<-renderTable(
    {
      
      dftest2<-filter(dftest(),Variety=="Test1", Week>25 )
      dftest2
    }
  )
```

What I found is after publishing the app on shinyapps.io any changes made to the excel sheet "CSV" do not show up. What I want is I can add data to the original excel sheet the app on shiny apps auto updates with the new data. Am I approaching this problem completely wrong? Or is it even possible via shinyapps.io ?