# Set parameters of a function which is itself a parameter of a function

Tags: r, function, parameters

I have a R function :

```
smallFunction <- function(x,y=2,z=3){ x+y+z }
```

I want to define the result of this function as the default value of a parameter of a bigger one :

```
bigFunction <- function(a,b,x,c=smallFunction(x,y,z))
```

How can I define y and z values ? Knowing that they could be define or left at their default values.
I don't really want to do such a thing :

```
bigFunction <- function(a,b,x,c=smallFunction(x,y,z),y=2,z=3)
```

because in reality I have a lot of default parameters for the smallFunction

I would rather something like :

```
bigFunction <- function(a,b,x,c=smallFunction(x,y,z),...)
```

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean that y and z could be defined? They could exist in the global environment?

Comment: THe user should be able to enter manually the value when calling the function without storing the values in global environement. Is their any way to do that ?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Yes, the answer below and my comment on it are alternative ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `...` from `bigFunction` to `smallFunction`

```
smallFunction <- function(x, y=2, z=3){ x+y+z }
bigFunction <- function(a,b,x, func=smallFunction, ...) { a+b+x+func(x=x, ...) }
```

For example,

```
bigFunction(1, 2, 3, y=10)
# [1] 22
```

As mentioned by @Frank you could do something like this to simplify the function body

```
bigFunction <- function(a,b,x, func=smallFunction, ...) {
    tmp <- func(x=x, ...)
    a+b+x+tmp
}
```

Comment: gorgeous way to do. Thanks

Comment: The `tmp` function is a great idea, got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4125300/2343633

Comment: @rbatt that's a really good question/answers, have that in my favorites :)