# Pass extra (dots) arguments with same name to different internal functions

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a function `f(...)` which internally calls different functions which both happen to take arguments with the name `color`. In some cases I want to send my `...` argument to one, and sometimes the other. **Is there some way to specify which one I mean when calling `f()`?**

Here's a simple example.

```r
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(...) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(...), ...)
}

# in this case I want it OUTSIDE aes()
f(color = "blue") # should be geom_point(color = blue)
```

[image]

```r
# here I want it INSIDE aes()
f(color = cyl) # should be geom_point(aes(color = cyl))
#> Error in list2(na.rm = na.rm, ...): object 'cyl' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It doesn't truly work in your first example It only works because `aes(col = 'abc')` itself doesn't return an error, but rather creates a single level factor, which then gets overwritten by `color = 'abc'` in the outer level by default behaviour in `geom_point`. How would you distinguish between the 2 yourself? There's no naming difference between the 2, so you'd have to capture the input, test whether `color` or `colour` is included, and whether it is a name contained in `.data` or not, and pass it to the correct layer respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r. The `...` all goes in one bucket. If you have a list of different arguments name they you can manually split them up in a messy way, but if they both have the same parameter names, then `...` probably isn't the best way to pass parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver for explaining what was happening here. As both comments make clear, it sounds like this is fundamentally the wrong way to approach this. I will tweak my question and add an answer just to provide closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is necessarily ambiguous to provide two different function arguments with the same name in the same function. Therefore using `...` is probably not the best way to do this. Possible solutions can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r) thread.

In the example, the argument `color` is getting passed from `...` to *BOTH* `aes()` and `geom_point()` because they both take a `color` argument. The reason the first example works is because supplying `color = "blue"` in both places doesn't throw an error.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "blue"), color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Finally, with a small tweak to the original function, it would be possible to make it flexible to provide `color` to either part of the function, but the approach probably wouldn't extend past this narrow use case much so probably not much help.

```r
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(...) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
    geom_point(...)
}

f(color = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
f(aes(color = factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>